# There is an integer multiple of each real to get close to an integer

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{Q}$. I want to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists integers $m$ and $n$ such that 
\begin{equation}
n\in(m\alpha-\varepsilon, m\alpha+\varepsilon)
\end{equation}
Obviously, $\alpha$ doesn't have any integer multiple (integer multiple). I tried a proof by contradiction, but didn't work and don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Do you know rationals are dense in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: Yes, of course. I don't see how that helps though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f=\inf \{|m\alpha -n|: m,n \in \Bbb Z\}\backslash \{0\}.$ Suppose (by contradiction) that $f>0.$ We have $f< 1/2.$ (Let $m=1$ and let $n$ be the nearest integer to $\alpha.$ )

Take $m,n \in \Bbb Z$ such that $f\leq |m\alpha-n|<3f/2.$

For brevity let $g=m\alpha - n.$ We have $0<|g|<1.$

$\bullet \;$ There exists $k\in \Bbb N$ such that $k|g|<1<(k+1)|g|.$ ( We cannot have $k|g|=1$ or $(k+1)|g|=1 $ for any $k\in \Bbb N,$ else $g,$ and hence $x$ also, is rational.)

The positive numbers $1-k|g|$ and $(k+1)|g|-1$ add to $|g|$ so their minimum is at most $|g|/2.$

$\bullet \;$ So $0<\min (1-k|g|, (k+1)|g|-1)< |g|/2.$ (We cannot have a min of  $|g|/2,$ else $g$ is rational.)

Let $k'=k$ if $1-k|g|< |g|/2.$ Otherwise let $k'=k+1.$ In both cases we have $0<|\;k'|g|-1|< |g|/2.$

Let $m'=mk'$ and $n'=nk'.$

Now if $g>0$ then $0<|m'\alpha - (n'+1)|=|\;k'|g|-1|<|g|/2<(3f/2)/2=3f/4<f,$ contrary to the definition of $f.$

Or if $g<0$ then $0<|m'\alpha- (n'-1)|=|\;k'|g|-1|< |g|/2<(3f/2)/2=3f/4<f,$ again a contradiction.

Comment: A partial converse to this: Let $S=\{|m\alpha-n|:m,n\in \Bbb Z\}\setminus \{0\}).$  If $\inf S =0$ then $\alpha \not \in \Bbb Q. $ Because  if $\alpha =c/d$ with $c,d \in \Bbb Z$ then $|m\alpha-n|\neq 0\implies$ $ |mc-nd|= |md\alpha -nd|\neq 0 $ $  \implies |mc-nd|\geq 1$ $ \implies |m\alpha-n|=|mc-nd|\cdot 1/|d|\geq 1/|d|,$ so there are no members of $S$ in the interval $(0,1/|d|).$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:   by [Dirichlet's approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem) the inequality $\left|\alpha -
 \dfrac{n}{m}\right| \lt \dfrac{1}{m^2}$ with irrational $\alpha$ is satisfied for infinitely many integers $n, m$. Note that this is the same as $-\dfrac{1}{m}\lt m \alpha - n \lt \dfrac{1}{m}$.

Comment: The sharpest possible version is that $|\alpha-n/m|<1/(m^2\sqrt 5)$ for infinitely many $(m,n)\in \Bbb Z^2.$.... We cannot replace $\sqrt 5$ with anything larger, for all irrational $\alpha.$.... If $\alpha =(1+\sqrt 5)/2$  and $k>\sqrt 5\;$ there are only finitely many $(m,n)\in \Bbb Z^2$ such that  $| \alpha-n/m|\leq 1/(m^2k).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Right, and also $2$ is the *best* exponent in the sense of [Roth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roth%27s_theorem) that the proposition does not hold true for algebraic numbers with $1/m^{2 + \epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Comment: Roth got a Fields medal for that result.

Comment: I quess my question follows quite directly from the theorem. Should have know this.

Comment: @AndrewBacinsky Right. Just choose such a pair $m,n$ with $m \gt 1 / \epsilon$.